# Are these try/catch'es equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

**Scenario**

I have a method that does database operation (let's say). If during that operation any exception is raised, I just want to throw that exception to the caller. I don't want to do any specific task in the catch block, assuming caller will do whatever it wants to do with that exception. In this scenario, which one is appropriate exception handling technique?

```
try
{
    // Some work that may generate exception
}
catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Some final work
}
```

Is the above equivalent to the following try/catch/finally?

```
try
{
    // Some work that may generate exception
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Some final work
}
```

Is the above equivalent to the following try/finally?

```
try
{
    // Some work that may generate exception
}
finally
{
    // Some final work
}
```

Which one is better than the other? Which one should be used?

Comment: The question at the very bottom of your question post is rather difficult to answer because of those 3 I could only recommend the bottom one. In general it is not recommended to catch *all* exceptions and then simply rethrow them. I am assuming you intend to process them inside the catch block but in that case it depends on what you intend to do. If you intend to *log* the exception and simply rethrow, then yes, catching *any type of exception* might work but in almost all other cases you should only catch the exceptions you know how to handle.

Comment: Also, the first 2 differ from the last one in the regards that you don't *have* a catch block, but if that catch block is simply going to rethrow the exception anyway (as your examples do), and no extra/other processing, then having the catch blocks at all seems dubious.

Comment: Basically, what to recommend doing depends on context that you don't have in your question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If you ask "Which one is better than the others" it doesn't *have* to be opinion based if there is a objective way to measure the "goodness" of each alternative. My point is rather that there is not enough context in this question to recommend anything at all other than to come up with more specific scenarios for which there very well may exist good and solid recommendations.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
I have added my scenario

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have added my scenario

Comment: With the new scenario at the top, if you don't intend to do anything at all with any exceptions you need nothing at all. Exceptions will propagate up the calling stack (and in some cases across thread and task boundaries depending on the frameworks involved) without your help. It's only if you intend to *handle* the exception you need to use try/catch. try/finally might be needed if you want to ensure some cleanup code always runs though. In other words, for your specific scenario, use the try/finally alternative if required, or no try/catch/finally at all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. They *may* be equivalent in some cases, but the general answer is no.

## Different kinds of `catch` blocks

### `catch` block with a specified exception type

The following will only catch managed exceptions that inherit from `System.Exception` and then executes the `finally` block, which will happen regardless of whether an exception was thrown or not.

```
try
{
   // Some work that may generate exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
finally
{
   // Some final work
}
```

### `catch` block without a specified exception type

The following `catch` block without a type specifier will also catch non-managed exceptions that are not necessarily represented by a managed `System.Exception` object, and then executes the `finally` block, which will happen regardless of whether an exception was thrown or not.

```
try
{
   // Some work that may generate exception
}
catch
{
   throw;
}
finally
{
   // Some final work
}
```

### `finally` block without a `catch` block

If you do not have a `catch` block at all, your `finally` will still be executed regardless of whether or not an exception occoured.

```
try
{
   // Some work that may generate exception
}
finally
{
  // Some final work
}
```

### When are they equivalent?

In case your `catch` block doesn't specify an exception and only contains the `throw;` statement, the last two are indeed equivalent. In case you don't care about non-managed exceptions and your `catch` block only contains the `throw;` statement, all three can be considered equivalent.

## Notes

### A note about `throw`

The following two pieces of code contain a subtle difference. The latter will *re-throw* the exception, meaning that it will rewrite the exception's stack trace, so these are definitely **not** equivalent:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

And

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

In case you use `finally` with an `IDisposable`, the following two pieces of code are almost equivalent, but with some subtle differences:

- When the object is null, the `using` statement won't give you a `NullReferenceException`
- When using the `try`-`finally` technique, the variable remains in scope, although it is **very** discouraged to use any object after it has been disposed. However you can still reassign the variable to something else.

  Something obj = null;
  try
  {
      obj = new Something()
      // Do something
  }
  finally
  {
      obj.Dispose();
  }

And

```
using (var obj = new Something())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I got the point Thank you. One more question. 
When throwing exception like throw e; it will write to exception's stack trace. Does this add extra performance impact on application.

Comment: @Bhuban There's no reason why you would want to do that. Either you want to rethrow, or you want to throw another exception (possibly with the original exception as `InnerException`). And of course, everything that needs to be done has a performance impact - only you can judge if a performance impact is noticeable in your application or not, and only through measurement. In general, exceptions are *exceptional*, so code that is expensive in an exceptional case is usually fine - if you find that throwing exceptions makes your program too slow, you should probably fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Note that 1 and 2 are *mostly* equivalent anyway, since unmanaged exceptions are wrapped to managed exceptions such as `SEHException` by the runtime. Technically, `catch { ... }` compiles to something like `catch (object) { ... }` - the CLI supports propagation of other object types, through the CLS mandates `System.Exception` as a base class for exceptions.

Comment: re. the `using` explanation: a difference is that the `obj` will still be in scope after the finally, which may be relavant.

Comment: @ths Indeed, although it is *very* bad practice to do anything with an object after it had been disposed.

Comment: One note about your `using` statement, the compiler handles the case where `obj` is `null` in the `finally` block.

Comment: Also in the `using` you can't reassign the value of `obj` but you can in the `try-finally`

Comment: I added your observations to my answer. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I presume all three are also equivalent if no exception is ever generated in the `try` block.

Comment: I take it by your answer that the `finally` block is always executed even if you throw from the `catch` block? That wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Maybe add a note to "A note about throw" recommending `throw` over `throw e`? There are legitimate reasons to re-throw an exception, but beginner programmers should default to `throw`.

Comment: I don't think is entirely accurate. As far as I know if you're throwing an exception from unmanaged code it is wrapped by the runtime in some kind of System.Exception subtype (SEHException and friends). On the other hand the CIL allows you to throw any kind of System.Object so while `catch {}` will be identical to `catch (Exception)` for non managed exceptions, the same isn't true if you throw System.String or co.

Comment: It shocks me this answer is accepted. No one of those code blocks will hit the finally part, because we are triggering unhandled exceptions from the catch block. It´s pretty straightforward to just copy/paste the code in a console application and prove it. Finally block is reached **only if the exception is handled**. If we surround those try/catch/finally examples in another try/catch, _then_ the inner finally will be hit, because that way the exception is not unhandled. But as the examples go, finally block will never be reached.

Comment: See  [Try/finally with no catch block](https://makolyte.com/csharp-try-finally-with-no-catch-block/#Unhandled_exceptions_and_the_finally_block) for an explanation.

Answer (score 11):

You have some good answers so far, but there is an interesting difference that they did not mention so far. Consider:

```
try { ImpersonateAdmin(); DoWork(); } 
finally { RevertImpersonation(); }
```

vs

```
try { ImpersonateAdmin(); DoWork(); }
catch { RevertImpersonation(); throw; }
finally { RevertImpersonation(); }
```

Suppose DoWork throws.

Now the first question at hand is "is there a catch block that can handle this exception", because if the answer is "no" then *the behaviour of the program is implementation-defined*.  The runtime might choose to terminate the process immediately, it might choose to run the finally blocks before it terminates the process, it might choose to start a debugger broken at the point of the unhandled exception, it might choose to do anything it likes.  Programs with unhandled exceptions are permitted to do anything.

So the runtime starts looking for a catch block. There's none in this try statement, so it looks up the call stack. Suppose it finds one with an exception filter. It needs to know if the filter will permit the exception to be handled, so the filter runs *before impersonation is reverted*. If the filter accidentally or deliberately does something that only an admin can do, it will succeed! This might not be what you want.

In the second example, the catch catches the exception immediately, reverts the impersonation, throws, and now the runtime starts looking for a catch block to handle the re-throw. Now if there is a filter it runs *after* the impersonation is reverted.   (And of course the finally then reverts again; I assume that reverting impersonation is idempotent here.)

This is an important difference between these two code snippets. If it is *absolutely positively forbidden* for *any* code to see the global state that was messed up by the try and cleaned up by the finally, then you have to catch before finally.  "Finally" does not mean "immediately", it means "eventually".

Answer (score 4):

Both of the `try / catch` statements are equivalent in that they are re-throwing the original exception that was caught. However the empty `catch` is more broad (as Venemo has already stated, catching unmanaged exceptions). If you are to `catch` an exception and capture it in a variable you can use it for logging or you can `throw` a new exception while passing the original exception as an argument - making it the ["inner exception"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `finally` is going to function the same regardless.

> Which one should be used, in a scenario where we don't need logging exception and we explicitly assume caller will handle exception being raised like writing in file stream or sending email.

If the caller will handle the exception and you do not need to log the occurrence of the exception at this level, then you should not be catching at all. If the caller will handle an exception being thrown, there is no need to catch an exception just to re-throw it.

Valid reasons to catch an exception that will be re-thrown:

- `throw new Exception("WTF Happened", ex); // Use as inner exception`
- Log exception
- Use a `finally` block to execute some cleanup code